# Where can be found all the Global Variables of VisualStudio?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Where can I find/see the list of avaliable Global Variables of VisualStudio that can be used in a designer file such as `$rootnamespace$` ?

Comment: What is a 'designer file'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [documentation article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eehb4faa.aspx) has a few of them listed.
But to get all of them, you can implement your own [wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185301.aspx), and then in the [`IWizard.RunStarted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.templatewizard.iwizard.runstarted.aspx) you'll receive those parameters with their respective values in the `replacementsDictionary` argument, then you can view them in the debug mode or save to a file.

```
void RunStarted(
    Object automationObject,  
    Dictionary<string, string> replacementsDictionary,
    WizardRunKind runKind,  
    Object[] customParams  
)
```